# Pass Javascript Alert a Value

Tags: variables, javascript

I'm looking for a [simple](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_popup.asp) javascscript alert box.  I need to be able to pass the alert box a string of text.

Is something like this possible? My syntax is probably wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert()
{
alert(my_string_here);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" string="alert for system number 2" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know my example makes no sense, I'm not a JS guru.  thank you Bjorn for the tip, that worked perfect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert(my_string)
{
alert(my_string);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="show_alert('This will alert!')" value="Show alert box" string="alert for system number 2" />

</body>
</html>
```

This makes no sense thou. Better solution:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="alert('Doh!')" value="Show alert box" string="alert for system number 2" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: although hopefully you're not still using inline event handlers for everything...

Comment: No, but _this_ example didn't make any sense. There's no need to create a separate function that does _the exact same thing_ as a regular alert() does.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alert('alert for system number 2');" value="Show alert box" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert("alert for system number 2");`

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? alert('Your string here') should do the trick if you really need an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

function testAlert(val){alert(val);}

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testAlert(val){alert(val);}
</script>

<input type=text onclick='testAlert(this.string)' string="something" value="clik here">
```